# Ubuntu 13.10 C++ OpenGL GLUT - linking issues - undefined reference to `glClearColor'

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, ubuntu, freeglut

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and trying to compile that portion of sample OpenGL code:

```
#include "GL/freeglut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"

/* display function - code from:
     http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter01.html
This is the actual usage of the OpenGL library.
The following code is the same for any platform */
void renderFunction()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

/* Main method - main entry point of application
the freeglut library does the window creation work for us,
regardless of the platform. */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL - First window demo");
    glutDisplayFunc(renderFunction);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I've used Eclipse to build the project, however it fails on linking level:

```
Building target: opengl_test
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/fglrx -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa -o "opengl_test"  ./src/opengl_test.o   
./src/opengl_test.o: In function `renderFunction()':
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `glClearColor'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:11: undefined reference to `glClear'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `glColor3f'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:13: undefined reference to `glOrtho'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:14: undefined reference to `glBegin'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:15: undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:16: undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:17: undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:18: undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:19: undefined reference to `glEnd'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:20: undefined reference to `glFlush'
./src/opengl_test.o: In function `main':
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:28: undefined reference to `glutInit'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:29: undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:30: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:31: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:32: undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:33: undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
/var/www/opengl_test/Debug/../src/opengl_test.cpp:34: undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opengl_test] Error 1
```

... so I've tried G++:

```
g++ -lGL -lglut opengl_test.cpp  -o test
```

However it gives pretty much the same output as Eclipse one.

I thought that maybe I need symlink necessary libs manually to /usr/lib.
I've searched for libs:

```
$ sudo apt-file search libGL.so
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
fglrx: /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
libgl1-mesa-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
libgl1-mesa-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
libgl1-mesa-glx: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-glx: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
libgl1-mesa-glx-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so.1
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so.173.14.37
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so.1
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so.173.14.37
nvidia-304: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so
nvidia-304: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.304.88
nvidia-304: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so
nvidia-304: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.304.88
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.304.108
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.304.108
nvidia-319: /usr/lib/nvidia-319/libGL.so
nvidia-319: /usr/lib/nvidia-319/libGL.so.1
nvidia-319: /usr/lib/nvidia-319/libGL.so.319.32
nvidia-319: /usr/lib32/nvidia-319/libGL.so
nvidia-319: /usr/lib32/nvidia-319/libGL.so.1
nvidia-319: /usr/lib32/nvidia-319/libGL.so.319.32
nvidia-319-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-319-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-319-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.319.60
nvidia-319-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-319-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-319-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.319.60
primus-libs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus/libGL.so.1
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-file search libglut.so
freeglut3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
freeglut3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
freeglut3-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so
```

Made symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so /usr/lib/libGL.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/libglut.so
```

However it still did not help. The same linking issue appeared.

1. How do I debug that issue?
2. How do I know which lib to choose and link them to /usr/lib? I chose fglrx, because my GPU drivers are running fglrx.
3. Do I need each time to link library manually from /usr/lib..../somewhere to /usr/lib?

Comment: It's a shame. Could not find the answer using Google, but found the answer via related panel on Stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203577/freeglut-linking-issues-in-linux?rq=1

Still need to work out why does Eclipse fail, but that's the Eclipse itself related.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting your libraries after the source file:

```
g++ opengl_test.cpp -lGL -lglut
```

To get Eclipse working you need to change so called "command line pattern". I am not Eclipse user actually, but try to check settings here: `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross G++ Linker`, or some other Linker-related settings.

Clarification: current `ld` defaults to link with `--as-needed` flag. In this mode before linking any library `ld` checks that some symbols from this library needed somewhere. `ld` perform this checks in order, so if you link something before your source file this library gets excluded. This behaviour can be disabled using `-Wl,--no-as-needed` `gcc` flag.

From `man ld`:

```
--as-needed
--no-as-needed
    This option affects ELF DT_NEEDED tags for dynamic  libraries  men-
    tioned on the command line after the --as-needed option.  Normally,
    the linker will add a DT_NEEDED tag for each dynamic     library  men-
    tioned  on  the  command line, regardless of whether the library is
    actually needed.  --as-needed causes     DT_NEEDED  tags  to  only  be
    emitted for libraries that satisfy some symbol reference from regu-
    lar objects which is undefined at the point that  the  library  was
    linked.  --no-as-needed restores the default behaviour.
```

Comment: Yes, that did it well. 
See my above comment, at the same time found an answer.
Anyway Thanks.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue Trying to find solution for Eclipse. Check my edit please.

Comment: I've managed to make a build using Eclipse, but I had to manualy add libraries:
GL
glut

I thought I can add just /usr/lib and all lib directly here in that folder would be available.
When I add that path Eclipse tries to build with -L/usr/lib but it gives same linker issues.

Comment: Try to pass `-Wl,--no-as-needed` flag please.

Comment: Thanks for explanation of --as-needed behaviour.

My Eclipse issues was that I did not includ the libraries separately. When I've specified them, Eclipse created correct command order so, --no-as-needed flag it's not necessary right now. I've just thought that if I pass -L flag it will grab all the necessary libs. The -L it's just dir path where shoud linker search and you still need to use -l flag to give the libraries. Anyway thanks for proactivity.