# Errors when compiling with GLUT program

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

It is impossible to compile an error.
Please help, who faced a similar problem?
OS: Ubuntu
IDE: Clion

CMakeFiles/a4_waves_OpenGL.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `display()':
/home/alex/ClionProjects/test/a4-waves_OpenGL/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to`glClear'

..............................

/home/alex/ClionProjects/test/a4-waves_OpenGL/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `glColor3f'
/home/alex/ClionProjects/test/a4-waves_OpenGL/main.cpp:42: undefined reference to`glutMainLoop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [a4_waves_OpenGL] Error 1

code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
using namespace std;

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   ///очистим буфер

    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); ///зададим цвет которым будем "рисовать". Я выбрал зелёный.
    glBegin(GL_LINES);   ///начнём рисовать первую координатную ось - OX. Будем это делать при помощи линий
    glVertex2f(-550,0);   ///первая точка оси
    glVertex2f(550,0);   ///вторая точка оси
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);  ////теперь проделаем тоже для оси OY
    glVertex2f(0,150);
    glVertex2f(0,-150);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);   ///начнём рисовать синусоиду при помощи ломаной линии
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); ///выберем для неё красный цвет

    for (int i = -500; i <= 500; i++) {
        float y = 100 * sin(i*M_PI/180);    ///вычислим текущую координату Y. Функция Sin() принимает значение в радианах, поэтому i следует умножить на число Пи и разделить на 180. Весь результат умножим на 100, указав тем самым максимальную высоту нашей синусоиды.
        glVertex2d(i,y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc,argv); ///инициализируем glut
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); ///использовать 1 буфер, и цвет типа RGB (3 составляющие)
    glutInitWindowSize(240,240); ///зададим размер окна 240x240
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);  ///позиция открытия окна
    glutCreateWindow("Sin"); ///создать окно с именем "Sin"
    glClearColor(1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0); ///цвет фона окна
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-600.0,600.0,-200.0,200.0,-1.0,1.0); ///зададим размеры координатной сетки
    glutDisplayFunc(display); ///зададим функцию отображающую необходимые объекты
    glutMainLoop();  ///передает управление в glut
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: g++ main.cpp -lGL -lglut

Answer (score 0):

An undefined reference means, that the linker cannot find one or more of the function definitions (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)).

In your case, you are most probably not linking agains opengl32 (`-lGL`). If you haven't done this yet, you will also need to link agains glut (`-lglut`). Have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203577/freeglut-linking-issues-in-linux) to see how this has to be done.